# Drupal 8 - Config-Import how to skip some specifics *.settings.yml

Tags: symfony, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I have a question about the **Config-Import** of Drupal 8.

I try to avoid the **Config-Import to delete** some of my *custom_module.settings.yml* **files on production**.

To achieve that goal I try to use the `ConfigEvents::DELETE` and the `$event->stopPropagation();` but it seems not working.

So, How could I stop a config-import of a specific file for example : *my_module.settings.yml* to be delete by the cim ?

*PS:*

- The --partial flag can't do the job, indeed I juste want to skip some
  exception but not every delete.
- The --skip-module flag only skip
  module installation not deletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realise my mistake by using the **Configuration API** instead of the **State API**.

I create an full article about this on my Agency Web Site: [Drupal 8 - Differences between Configuration API & State API](https://antistatique.net/en/we/blog/2016/06/14/drupal-8-differences-between-configuration-api-state-api)